# How to make a circle a real circle? How to change the real distance between the marks on the axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, geometry

[image]

As you can see this is a perfect circle drawn with matplotlib, nevertheless, it is not, it looks like an ellipse. I need to change the distance between the markers on the axles to be the same, of course, in 2D I can change it manually once the plot is made, but I need to do this in 3D.

I expect this but made in code
[image]